# jQVMap - Tooltips show hide option

Tags: hide, show, tooltip, jqvmap

I have a JQVMap that is showing Tooltips on each region, but in my map there are some region where i don't want to show tooltips - Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

It`s described in jqvmap documentation:

> Consider that fact that you can use standard features of jQuery events
>   like event.preventDefault() or returning false from the callback to
>   prevent default behavior of JQVMap (showing label or changing country
>   color on hover). In the following example, when user moves mouse
>   cursor over Canada label won't be shown and color of country won't be
>   changed. At the same label for Russia will have custom text.

```
  jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap(
{
    onLabelShow: function(event, label, code)
    {
        if (code == 'ca')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else if (code == 'ru')
        {
            label.text('Bears, vodka, balalaika');
        }
    },
    onRegionOver: function(event, code)
    {
        if (code == 'ca')
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works and i like the way you explain it

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer is correct you can mark it like "answered", it will help other users. Thank you!